# Adjusting image brightness

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

For windows phone app, when I am adjusting brightness by slider it works fine when I
move it to right. But when I go back to previous position, instead of image darkening, it goes brighter and brighter. Here is my code based on pixel manipulation.

```cs
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {

        wrBmp = new WriteableBitmap(Image1, null);


        for (int i = 0; i < wrBmp.Pixels.Count(); i++)
        {
            int pixel = wrBmp.Pixels[i];
            int B = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int G = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int R = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int A = (int)(pixel);

            B += (int)slider1.Value; R += (int)slider1.Value; G += (int)slider1.Value;
            if (R > 255) R = 255; if (G > 255) G = 255; if (B > 255) B = 255;
            if (R < 0) R = 0; if (G < 0) G = 0; if (B < 0) B = 0;
            wrBmp.Pixels[i] = B | (G << 8) | (R << 16) | (A << 24);
        }
        wrBmp.Invalidate();
        Image1.Source = wrBmp;

    }
```

What am I missing and is there any problem with slider value. I am working with small images as usual in mobiles. I have already tried copying original image to duplicate one. I think code is perfect, after a lot of research I found that the problem is due to slider value.Possible solution is assigning initial value to slider. I want some code help.

private double lastSlider3Vlaue;
 private void slider3_ValueChanged(object sender,`RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (slider3 == null) return;
        double[] contrastArray = { 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.4, 2.6, 2.9 };
        double CFactor = 0;
        int nIndex = 0;
        nIndex = (int)slider3.Value - (int)lastSlider3Vlaue;
        if (nIndex < 0)
        {
            nIndex = (int)lastSlider3Vlaue - (int)slider3.Value;
            this.lastSlider3Vlaue = slider3.Value;
            CFactor = contrastArray[nIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            nIndex = (int)slider3.Value - (int)lastSlider3Vlaue;
            this.lastSlider3Vlaue = slider3.Value;
            CFactor = contrastArray[nIndex];
        }

        WriteableBitmap wbOriginal;
        wbOriginal = new WriteableBitmap(Image1, null);
        wrBmp = new WriteableBitmap(wbOriginal.PixelWidth, wbOriginal.PixelHeight);
        wbOriginal.Pixels.CopyTo(wrBmp.Pixels, 0);
        int h = wrBmp.PixelHeight;
        int w = wrBmp.PixelWidth;
        for (int i = 0; i < wrBmp.Pixels.Count(); i++)
        {
            int pixel = wrBmp.Pixels[i];
            int B = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int G = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int R = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int A = (int)(pixel);

            R = (int)(((R - 128) * CFactor) + 128);
            G = (int)(((G - 128) * CFactor) + 128);
            B = (int)(((B - 128) * CFactor) + 128);

            if (R > 255) R = 255; if (G > 255) G = 255; if (B > 255) B = 255;
            if (R < 0) R = 0; if (G < 0) G = 0; if (B < 0) B = 0;
            wrBmp.Pixels[i] = B | (G << 8) | (R << 16) | (A << 24);
        }

        wrBmp.Invalidate();
        Image1.Source = wrBmp;
```

}

After debugging I found that the r g b values are decreasing continuosly when sliding forward,but when sliding backwards it is also decreasing where as it shoul increase.
please help iam working on this since past last three months.Besides this u also give me advice about how i can complete this whole image processing

Comment: If you always add a value to the rgb values, they will always get brighter. I don't think that you have negative slider values?

Comment: hey ,thanks for considering this question,in xaml i have set maximum and minimum for slider 100 and -100 respectively.so thumd in slider is in middle initially,so it has negative value it slides backward,but as u said when moving forward,then moving backward it does not have any positive value.So i already know this problem.I wanted help from ur side,that how can i resolve this problem by slider values

Comment: Then you should store the initial values and add the slider value to those. E.g. save a copy of the original image.

Comment: because of nobody is replying,I agin posted this question,I really want some help

Comment: Hey nico,how to store the initial values.and pls give me some codes regarding this

Comment: Please do NOT repost questions because you think they aren't getting enough attention. Edit the original question to make it better - this will bump the question onto the homepage again and make it more likely that people will answer.

Comment: Hey Nico,Can please tell me how to know whether slider is moving forward or backward in c# code.If it can be known then it will be the best solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. Each time the slider's value changes, you're adding that value to the picture's brightness. What makes your logic flawed is that the value returned by the slider will always be positive, and you're always adding the brightness to the **same** picture.

So, if the slider starts with a value of 10, I'll add 10 to the picture's brightness.

Then,  I slide to 5. I'll add 5 to the **previous picture's** brightness (the one you already added 10 of brightness to).

Two ways to solve the issue:

1. Keep a copy of the original picture, and duplicate it every time your method is called. Then add the brightness to the copy (and not the original). That's the safest way.
2. Instead of adding the new absolute value of the slider, calculate the relative value (how much it changed since the last time the method was called:

   ```
   private double lastSliderValue;

   private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
   {
       var offset = slider1.Value - this.lastSliderValue;
       this.lastSliderValue = slider1.Value;

       // Insert your old algorithm here, but replace occurences of "slider1.Value" by "offset"
   }
   ```

This second way can cause a few headaches though. Your algorithm is capping the RGB values to 255. In those cases, you are losing information and cannot revert back to the old state. For instance, take the extreme example of a slider value of 255. The algorithm sets all the pixels to 255, thus generating a white picture. Then you reduce the slider to 0, which should in theory restore the original picture. In this case, you'll subtract 255 to each pixel, but since every pixel's value is 255 you'll end up with a black picture.

Therefore, except if you find a clever way to solve the issue mentionned in the second solution, I'd recommand going with the first one.

Comment: Hey kookiz, I really appreciate ,that u have considered my qoestion,but its not working due to its offset's logic.if we are not assigning any value (means position) to lastSliderValue then offset will equal to slider1.value ,then why to declare offset,we can give directly slider1.value.But u have said that we have to give relative value that is right.Right now what we have assign lastSliderValue.Help....................

Comment: @bhupsiiiiiii... I'm not sure what's your point, but anyway the offset logic is flawed as I stated in my conclusion. Go with the first solution instead.

Comment: Hey kookiz,I have worked on ur first solution.But here also We need a slider,so for slider value change event what value sholud we assign to slider1.value.After researching I found that,after moving some +ve distance ,it adds some positive value,again after moving backwards little bit it is also adding according to slider1.value.So for this can u find a solution ,Iam also trying....

Comment: Hey Kookiz,Can please tell me how to know whether slider is moving forward or backward in c# code.If it can be known then it will be the best solution for this.

Comment: @bhupsiiiiiii... That's the code sample I've provided. Compare the value of the slider with the previous one: if the difference is positive then it has increased, if it's negative it has decreased. Then store the new value of the slider.

Comment: private double lastSliderValue;

private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var offset = slider1.Value - this.lastSliderValue;
    this.lastSliderValue = slider1.Value;

    // Insert your old algorithm here, but replace occurences of "slider1.Value" by "offset"
}

Comment: if this code u r telling ,then its not working,reason I have already told u.if we are not assigning any value (means position) to lastSliderValue then offset will equal to slider1.value ,then why to declare offset,we can give directly slider1.value

Comment: @bhupsiiiiiii... This code works if the initial value of your slider is 0. If your slider is initialized to another value, initialize the `lastSliderValue` variable with the same value (in the `OnNavigatedTo` event for instance)

Comment: @Kookiz-I got it what u want tell,but in my code initial value of slider is 0.its working when moving forward,again when moving back image is not getting to its original position ,because we have set initial value of lastslidervalue  to 0,so offset value will be always equal to slider1.value-this.lastSliderValue(0) i.e. offset is always equal to slider1.value.

Comment: @bhupsiiiiiii... `lastSliderValue` is only equal to 0 the first time. The next time you execute the method, `lastSliderValue` have the value we assigned the previous time. That's why the variable is declared outside of the scope of the method

Comment: ,Thanks a lot,I never guessed also it is so simple,not its working perfectly.But I have made little bit change to ur code,but it is almost similar to ur code.

Comment: @Kookiz-Thanks again kookiz

Comment: @Kookiz--Hey Brother,But in contrast

image is working perfectly when iam sliding forward,but when iam sliding backwards image is not returning to its original position.Here is my code---

Comment: my max value for slider is 9 and min value is 0

Comment: @Kookiz--Pls try this,tell me if u have any problem